# What pieces do I need to make suit swappers from the Lego Batman video game?

Tags: building, video-games

My son has asked Santa to bring him Lego Batman suit swappers to use with his minifigures, both Batman and Robin versions. Can anyone advise as to what pieces are needed for these? All help is very much appreciated by Santa and his elves.

Answer (score 2):

You mean one of these?

[image]

Basically, you'll need two circle of these 4 x 4 corner bricks:

[image]

Separated by some of these Plate 1 x 2 with Handle:

[image]

I don't think the centre red tile with an "R" on it exists, so I think you'll have to make one out of card or something.

Comment: Which will get you close, but sadly not all the way there - the outer corner pieces are plates, not bricks, but I can't seem to find any real parts like that - the closest I got is a [full quarter circle](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/30565) :( The centre tile is usually in 4 parts in the game, but even like that doesn't appear to actually exist.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid You're right, the required parts don't actually exist. I think the parts I've suggested are the best you can do.